# Riverpod providers only updating after the app restarts once and after that they work as intended

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have 3 riverpod providers which should show totals in a stats_page and they work perfectly only after hot restarting the app once and then after that they show updated in real time as intended, the flow is a user adds a studySessions and I have a streamProivder watching the studySessions collection and returning it, then filteredStudySessionsProvider watches it and filters is by day week or month:

```
part 'filtered_study_sessions.g.dart';

@riverpod
class FilteredStudySessions extends _$FilteredStudySessions {
  @override
  Future<List<StudySession>> build() async {
    print('filteredStudySessionsProvider Initialised');
    //make it watch allStudySessionProvider and then return the approprate list

    final filter = ref.watch(filterProvider);
    final asyncValue = ref.watch(allStudySessionsProvider);
    // Handle different states of AsyncValue
    return asyncValue.when(
      loading: () {
        print('filteredStudysessions loading');
        // Return some default TotalsModel when loading
        return [];
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        // Handle error case, for example, log the error
        print('Error loading study sessions: $error');
        return [];
      },
      data: (List<StudySession> studysessions) {
        print('filteredStudysessions finished loading');
        switch (filter) {
          case Filter.Daily:
            return studysessions
                .where((session) => isSameDay(session.endTime, DateTime.now()))
                .toList();
          case Filter.Weekly:
            return studysessions
                .where((session) => isSameWeek(session.endTime, DateTime.now()))
                .toList();
          case Filter.Monthly:
            return studysessions
                .where(
                    (session) => isSameMonth(session.endTime, DateTime.now()))
                .toList();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

then I have a provider that groups the studySessions by topic and watches this filteredStudySessionlist:

```
/this class will take the FilteredStudySessions and group them by taskName totaling their focusTime and Interruptions
@riverpod
class FilteredGroupedStudySessions extends _$FilteredGroupedStudySessions {
  @override
  Future<List<StudySession>> build() async {
    print('filteredGroupStudySessionsProvider Initialised');
    final studysessions = ref.watch(filteredStudySessionsProvider);
    return studysessions.when(
      loading: () {
        print('loading filteredGroupStudySessionProvider');
        // Return some default TotalsModel when loading
        return [];
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        // Handle error case, for example, log the error
        print('Error loading study sessions: $error');
        return [];
      },
      data: (List<StudySession> studysessions) {
        print('finished loading filteredGroupStudySessionProvider');
        // Group study sessions by task name
        final groupedSessions =
            groupBy(studysessions, (session) => session.taskName);

        // Create a list of study sessions with combined focus time and interruptions
        final result = groupedSessions.values.map((sessions) {
          final combinedFocusTime = sessions
              .map((session) => session.focusTimeInSeconds)
              .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
          final combinedInterruptions = sessions
              .map((session) => session.interruptions)
              .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

          // Assuming the other properties like startTime, endTime, etc., are the same for all sessions
          return StudySession(
            taskName: sessions.first.taskName,
            endTime: sessions.first.endTime,
            focusTimeInSeconds: combinedFocusTime,
            interruptions: combinedInterruptions,
            // Add other properties as needed
          );
        }).toList();

        return result;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Additionally I also have a totalsProcider which also watches this filtered list and returns a totals model:

```
d
class Totals extends _$Totals {
  @override
  TotalsModel build() {
    final asyncValue = ref.watch(filteredStudySessionsProvider);
    print('TotalsProvider Initialised');

    // Handle different states of AsyncValue
    return asyncValue.when(
      loading: () {
        print('totalsProvider loading');
        // Return some default TotalsModel when loading
        return TotalsModel(
            totalSessions: 0, interruptions: 0, focusTimeInSeconds: 0);
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        // Handle error case, for example, log the error
        print('Error loading study sessions: $error');
        return TotalsModel(
            totalSessions: 0, interruptions: 0, focusTimeInSeconds: 0);
      },
      data: (List<StudySession> studysessions) {
        print('Totals finished loading');
        if (studysessions.isEmpty) {
          return TotalsModel(
              totalSessions: 0, interruptions: 0, focusTimeInSeconds: 0);
        }

        // Filter the sessions that occurred today
        List<StudySession> todaysSessions = studysessions.toList();

        // Initialize the totals with zeros
        TotalsModel totalsModel = TotalsModel(
            totalSessions: 0, interruptions: 0, focusTimeInSeconds: 0);

        // Iterate through the list of StudySessions and accumulate totals
        for (StudySession session in todaysSessions) {
          totalsModel = TotalsModel(
              totalSessions: totalsModel.totalSessions + 1,
              interruptions: totalsModel.interruptions + session.interruptions,
              focusTimeInSeconds:
                  totalsModel.focusTimeInSeconds + session.focusTimeInSeconds);
        }

        // Return the accumulated TotalsModel
        return totalsModel;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have added print state to show when its loading and done loading for each providers:

User

```
Here is the new output: [GoRouter] going to /statspage
I/flutter (14315): filteredStudySessionsProvider Initialised
I/flutter (14315): filteredStudysessions finished loading
I/flutter (14315): filteredGroupStudySessionsProvider Initialised
I/flutter (14315): loading filteredGroupStudySessionProvider
I/flutter (14315): TotalsProvider Initialised
I/flutter (14315): totalsProvider loading
I/flutter (14315): filteredGroupStudySessionsProvider Initialised
I/flutter (14315): finished loading filteredGroupStudySessionProvider
I/flutter (14315): TotalsProvider Initialised
I/flutter (14315): Totals finished loading
```

when I hot restart the app just once these providers update in real time and work perfectly but when I run the app for the first time they refuse to update when new StudySessions are written, what could be causing this behavior?

FilteredStudySessionsProvider is getting used in the stats page:

```
he todays sessions widget on the homepage
class StatsPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const StatsPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<StatsPage> createState() => _StatsPageState();
}

class _StatsPageState extends ConsumerState<StatsPage> {
  int? sliding = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var filter = ref.watch(filterProvider);
    ref.watch(filteredStudySessionsProvider);

    //ref.watch(userAuthProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 58,
        leading: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    GoRouter.of(context).go('/home/settimer');
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 27,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: const [
          ChangeThemeButton(),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10,
              bottom: 10,
            ),
            height: 35,
            width: 180,
            child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
              children: {
                0: Text(
                  'Day',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                ),
                1: Text(
                  'Week',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                ),
                2: Text(
                  'Month',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                ),
              },
              groupValue: sliding,
              onValueChanged: (int? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  print(sliding);
                  sliding = newValue;
                  if (sliding == 0) {
                    ref.read(filterProvider.notifier).state = Filter.Daily;
                  } else if (sliding == 1) {
                    ref.read(filterProvider.notifier).state = Filter.Weekly;
                  } else {
                    ref.read(filterProvider.notifier).state = Filter.Monthly;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          // Align(
          //   alignment: Alignment.center,
          //   child: Container(
          //     margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, top: 30),
          //     child: Text(
          //       '${ref.watch(filterProvider).toString().split('.')[1]} Total',
          //       style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
          //     ),
          //   ),
          // ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 30),
              child: Text(
                '${filter.toString().split('.')[1]} Total',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //Expanded(flex: 9, child: TotalStats()),
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: TodayNewTotals()),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, top: 45),
              child: Text(
                'By Topic',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Expanded(
            flex: 16,
            child: FilteredStudySessionList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then in those two custom widgets filterGroupStudySessionProvider and totalsProvider are getting watched.

This is the streamProvider:

```
@riverpod
class AllStudySessions extends _$AllStudySessions {
  @override
  Stream<List<StudySession>> build() {
    print('allStudySessionsProviderInitialised Initialised');
    final dbhandler = DBHandler();
    return dbhandler.getStudySessions();
  }
}
```

which calls this method:

```
  Stream<List<StudySession>> getStudySessions() {
    try {
      // Get the current user's UID
      String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
      DateTime today = DateTime.now();
      // DateTime endOfDay =
      //     DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 23, 59, 59);

      return FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users/$uid/studySessions')
          .snapshots()
          .map(
            (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
                .map((document) => StudySession.fromJson(document.data()))
                .toList(),
          );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting study sessions stream: $e');
      return Stream.value([]);
    }
  }


This is what is being printed on app startUp:
I/flutter (17561): allStudySessionsProviderInitialised Initialised
I/flutter (17561): Error getting study sessions stream: Null check operator used on a null value
```

after adding providerObserver this is what it said when the stats page was navigated to:

```
[GoRouter] going to /statspage
I/flutter (18418): TotalsProvider Initialised
I/flutter (18418): Totals finished loading
I/flutter (18418): Provider totalsProvider:AutoDisposeNotifierProviderImpl<Totals, TotalsModel>#f933f was initialized with Instance of 'TotalsModel'
I/flutter (18418): filteredGroupStudySessionsProvider Initialised
I/flutter (18418): finished loading filteredGroupStudySessionProvider
I/flutter (18418): Provider filteredGroupedStudySessionsProvider:AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderImpl<FilteredGroupedStudySessions, List<StudySession>>#32778 was initialized with AsyncLoading<List<StudySession>>()
I/flutter (18418): Provider filteredGroupedStudySessionsProvider:AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderImpl<FilteredGroupedStudySessions, List<StudySession>>#32778 updated from AsyncLoading<List<StudySession>>() to AsyncData<List<StudySession>>(value: [])
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you watching the providers? When you add a new study session, how the provider knows it? Are you invalidating the provider so the others watching can also be rebuilt?
Also, i would suggest you to instead of:

```
 return studysessions.when(
      loading: () {
        print('loading filteredGroupStudySessionProvider');
        // Return some default TotalsModel when loading
        return [];
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        // Handle error case, for example, log the error
        print('Error loading study sessions: $error');
        return [];
      },
      data: (List<StudySession> studysessions) {
        return studySessions }
```

### Do this instead

After all your session studies loaded:

```
final sessions = ref.watch(sessionsProvider).requireValue;
```

And then you treat the data. Or simply `await` the other providers; But I think you would only return `asyncValue.when` in widgets.

### Edit

I would also suggest you to add a provider observer so you can know when it got dispoed
[Logging and error reporting](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/provider_observer)

Comment: the studySessions is written to a firebase collection and I have a StreamProvider watching this so it gets updated according, the filteredStudySessionsProvider then watches this streamProvider

Comment: You need to check if filteredSessionsStudyProvider is being disposed. Because it watches the stream provider. But if it gets disposed, then the stream provider will also be disposed, because there's no provider watching it.

Comment: I am also watching that streamprovider in main

Comment: but you are right the only other place that stream is being watched is the filterStreamProvider what could do to fix this?

Comment: Is the document being updated in firestore? The filterStreamProvider, is it getting disposed? Can you confirm that the filterStreamProvider and the firestore stream provider are being watched all the time?

Comment: yes the moment the studySession is completed it gets written to firebase and then the streamProvider calls a method that retrieves all studySessions so it updates automatically, I am watching all providers in my MyApp, I will amend my answer to include more information

Comment: I have added my code for my homepage which is very similar to the stats page with the difference being I have a widget watching a stream and not a provider watching a stream

Comment: so allStudySessions streamProvider is being watched by filteredStudySessionProvider which is then being watched by 1.groupedStudySessionsProvider and 2.totalsProvider and only they are being used inside actual widget the other two are only called in MyApp

Comment: Could you show your widgets? Or send the repo